# Height of UIWebView contents

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios7

The method on `UIWebView` `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` works on most sites, but on some, https://twitter.com/parislemon/status/416125377249964032 for example, it returns nothing.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"Height = %f",[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"] floatValue]);

}
```

Is it `https` related? Are they blocking the JS some how? Redirects?

Comment: What do you mean it returns nothing? Does it call that delegate method at all or do you get a value for height - if so what is it?

Comment: You're right my description was terrible, nothing = zero - as in it Height = 0.0000;

Comment: Have you tried `webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;` instead of using javascript?